# how to send post with MULTIPART_FORM_DATA with @RequestBody in restful service

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I want to send `@RequestBody` as Post request to restful service.In `@RequestBody` I have `id`, `title`, `aboutMe`, and `image file`.I set `produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`but when i check in rest I get error that says
**406 not acceptable** .How can I solve it?

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "aboutMe", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String saveAboutMe(@RequestBody Author author) {
        authorService.saveAboutMe(author);
        return "saved";
    }
```

And entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm")
    @Column(name = "dateOfAuthor")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedTime;

    @Column(name = "aboutMe", length = 10000)
    private String aboutMe;

    @Column(name = "image")
    @Lob
    private Blob image;
}
```

Screenshot I get from rest [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyqLi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass with @RequestBody and Blob object, image should be MultipartFile object. So for working code:

1) Inject SessionFactory into controller class or in any class where you want to convert Mulitpart to Blob object

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

2) Changes for Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "aboutMe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveAboutMe(Author author,@RequestPart("image") MultipartFile imageFile) {
    //Convert Multipart file into BLOB
    try {
        Blob image = Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).createBlob(authorImage.getInputStream(),authorImage.getSize());
        author.setImage(image);
    } catch (HibernateException | IOException  exception) {
        log.error(exception.getMessage(),exception);
    }

    authorService.saveAboutMe(author);
    return "saved";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I changed my code, but now I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.Can this error related `@RequestPart` that image does not upload?Thanks in advance